A Notion of Continuity Based on Existence of Certain Sequences
I am interested in the name for the following notion of continuity:
Say that the function $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is $(??)-$continuous at $x$ if there exists a sequence $x_n\to x$ with $x_n\neq x$ such that $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$.
For instance, I believe this rules out removable discontinuities, but allows for functions that have jump discontinuities.
Does anyone know the proper term for this notion of continuity?

Consider "Potentially Continuous" , to highlight that it might not be so. Consider "Sequentially Continuous" , to highlight that there is such a Sequence. Either Case , we have to check out further.

This is not a good notion of continuity. For instance, let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any function that is discontinuous everywhere. Let $f'$ be the following modification of $f$:
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
0\ \text{, if } x=0\\
x\ \text{, if } x=\frac{1}{n} \text{ for some } n \in \mathbb{N}\\
f(x)\ \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Per your definition, this function is continuous at the point $0$.

I guess it depends what you mean by "good." As your example shows, this certainly does not correspond very closely to the usual notion of continuity. However, I think the notion is still interesting, since it characterizes points $f(x)$ that are "reachable" by some sequence $f(x_n)$.

Ok, yeah, the condition you're asking about might be interesting. It's just that I don't think it should be called as "something-continuous". Also, I think it's nice to formulate it (for a function $f: X \to Y$ between topological spaces and a point $x \in X$) as $f$ is continuous at $x$ if restricted to a subspace of $X$, of which $x$ is a limit point.

Also, I chatted with claude ai about this condition for a few minutes and it's not aware of anyone studying this condition or of it having a name.

Alternatively, it can be described as "f(x) is in the cluster set of f at x".
